# Remove all non-alphanumerical values from dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, str-replace

I'm trying to remove special characters from the rows in my data frame. so keep numbers and alphabets. I have tried this code but it also takes out the alphabet rows. Ultimately trying to remove the special characters

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("[^-0-9/.]+", "", x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
x <- "I'will remove all 999 - @ ?? -9/."

gsub("\\W", " ", x)

#> "I will remove all 999         9  "
```

if you want to remove the long spaces , use

```
gsub("\\W", " ", x) |> gsub("\\s{2,}" , " " , x = _)

#> "I will remove all 999 9 "
```